# Zip Password functionality works wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip, brute-force

I have a paradoxon, that I just cannot explain.
In short: I built a python script that is supposed to crack a zipped file, which is password protected.

This is what I've done:

(1) zip the text file:
`zip --password bla zip3.zip myZip` So the passphrase is "bla".

(2) Then I use the following Python Script:

```
import zipfile
import itertools
from itertools import *
import string
import time
```

That's the basic function, that is supposed to check, if a given password works or not:

```
def crack(File, pwd):
    try:
        File.extractall(pwd=str.encode(pwd))
        print("\n---- SUCCESS! {0} ----".format(pwd))
    except:
        print("{0} did not work.".format(pwd))
        pass
```

Here I specify, which characters I want to use for trying:
`myLetters = string.ascii_letters`

Here I specify, which zip-file I want to crack:
`File = zipfile.ZipFile("PATH/TO/MY/zip3.zip", 'r')`

Here I specify, how long the password-phrase is:
`pwd_len = 3`

here I specify, how many possible combinations of the charactes exist:
`all_poss = (len(myLetters)**pwd_len)`

Here is the procedure for concrete password cracking:

```
 count = 0
 start_time = time.time()
 for i in range(0,pwd_len+1):   
     for j in map(''.join, itertools.product(myLetters, repeat=i)):
         crack(File, j)  
         count += 1
 print(round((count/all_poss)*100, 1), end='\r')
 res_time = time.time() - start_time
 print("\n--- {} ---".format(round(res_time,2)))
```

I use a nested loop, to try every password. If it works, I should get the Success-message. Else I should only see the "doesn't work message".

However...

If I type in my terminal: `python3 pwdCracker.py >> out` I get a long text file, which contains many many "does not work messages", BUT I also get a whole bunch of "Success-messages", although only ONE ("bla") should be correct.

Here is a little extract:

```
wN did not work.
---- SUCCESS! wO ----
wO did not work.
wP did not work.`
```

So apparently "wO" is working.. But why?? I set the password to "bla"! I really can open the file with "wO"... why can that happen??

Hope you can help!

Comment: Are you saying that you can open the same password-encrypted zip file with both "bla" and "wO" as a password?

Comment: yes, I tried it many times.. I always end up in a situation, where the zip-file can be opened with a password, that is different from what I have set in the beginning ("bla"). In fact, there are hundreds of passwords that are accepted... maybe I'm using the zip-functionality in a wrong way..

Comment: If it is like that, then it's a zip bug, can you link the zipped file? Which zip did you use? in which OS?

Comment: Also, from your output looks that you get both "success" and "did not work" for "wO"

Comment: Yes, I think you are right... it must have something to do with the zip-file, I tried it with another file, that I have zipped and it worked.. I must have done something wrong with the initial zip file... I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

The default zip encryption is known to be weak, and I think you are seeing hash collisions [1](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-2591629/multiple-password-encrypted-zip.html),[2](http://quangntenemy.blogspot.co.uk/2008/10/winzip-password-collision.html).

Most encryption methods (including those used in zip files) need a fixed length key, and so the password is hashed to give that key. The hash function used in zip is crc32 (specified [here](http://math.ucr.edu/~mike/zipattacks.pdf), although it details a different attack) which was designed for error checking rather than cryptographic hashing. Therefore it will be vulnerable to this type of attack.

Answer (score 0):

The old zip format contains a check byte to quickly verify if your password is right or wrong. This check byte is verified against the last byte of the decrypted 'decryption header'.

Since the check byte is, well, only one byte, false positives happen quite frequently (1/256). What bruteforce crackers usually do in these cases is to check against multiple files from the same archive (hence using multiple check bytes).

From PkWare's APPNOTE.TXT:

> After the header is decrypted,  the last 1 or 2 bytes in Buffer SHOULD
>   be the high-order word/byte of the CRC for the file being decrypted,
>   stored in Intel low-byte/high-byte order.  Versions of PKZIP prior to
>   2.0 used a 2 byte CRC check; a 1 byte CRC check is used on versions after 2.0.
>   This can be used to test if the password supplied is correct or not.

So what you are seeing is just that, false positives.